# Printer Issues w/ Server 2k8 R2 and Windows 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, printing, drivers

We have an HP LaserJet 4000 and an HP Color LaserJet 3600, both trying to manage from Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 (Print Management) and deploy to Windows 7 x86.

**For the HP LaserJet 4000**: HP's site says "Install the driver included in Windows 7 or Windows Update "...and I can't find anywhere to download the actual drivers to add to the server. If you try to add the printer from Windows 7, it says it can't find any driver for it, unless you let it search Windows Update on the Win7 PC for the driver (which I don't want to allow users access to, originally I had it disabled because we use WSUS).

**For the HP Color LaserJet 3600**: There are no Windows 7 drivers, but I put the Vista drivers on the server. Now, there's tons of issues trying to print greyscale (it inverts the colors, so it uses a black background and white text) and single-sided always attempts to print duplex (where it print pages 2 4 6 and then wants you to put the paper back in to get 1 3 5).

Does anyone know where I can find working drivers for these to put our Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Call HP. If you take a look at the [faq], you'd see that this type of question falls under the umbrella of "Too Localized".

Comment: Well, if anyone knows about printing in grayscale inverting black&white, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a Windows 7 machine, install the printer on it, download the driver from MS Update, and copy that file off somewhere so you can install it on your print server.

Alternately, try downloading it through your WSUS server (though finding it may be a pain).

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer: Setup a print server and deploy the shared printer, the clients will download the drivers from the print server instead of Windows update.

Harder answer: Setup one and find the print drive in `%windir%\SoftwareDistribution` then copy to other computers or however you want to deploy the driver.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything that looks like a print driver in SoftwareDistribution, can you  be more specific?

Comment: After you've installed the printer from Windows Update the driver should be in the SoftwareDistribution folder. What it looks like (cab file, directory, etc) would depend on the exact driver.